# How to use "position: relative" properly in my case?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have recently started to code again after a long break and now I'm trying hard to see what is it that I'm doing wrong.

I made a JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mtsgp3gg/

This is the output I'd like to see: http://puu.sh/jwi3d/233c917986.png

I have a container with 3 images:

```
<div class="container">
   <img src="main picture">
   <img id="tape left" src="">
   <img id="tape right" src="">
</div>
```

I would like to put some little "tape thingies" over my main picture using `position: relative;` and `top:0;` but so far I failed.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

css `position:` is somewhat confusing, especially at the start (*and it is misused almost 99% of all times*).

You use `position: relative` because you want it to be *relative* to the container, right? Although this is the obvious behavior, *it is not what css does*.

`position: relative` means "I'll give you `top`/`right`/... values and want that the element is moved by that amount from *where it would occur normally*."

You almost always want to use `position: absolute` which basically means "pick the boundaries of the parent (being specific: the first parent that is not `position: static` which is the default) and move this element to what I define with `top`/`right`/...". (There are more implications like `absolute` removing the element from the document flow, but that's out of scope at the moment.)

This means you have to

1. position your container *not static*. `position: relative` works fine here, as it does not alter the element if you don't specify `top`/... .
2. position your items with `position: absolute` as they will then be defined relative to their container (not relative to their original position, as they would be with `position: relative`).

Your example would look like

```css
body {
    background: gray;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px; 
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: navy;
}

.container [id] {
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
}

.container #one {
    left: -5px;
}

.container #two {
    right: -5px;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://www.animal-photography.com/thumbs/blue_eyed_white_long_hair_cat_~AP-G3KLBP-TH.jpg">
    <img id="one" src="http://fenrir.info.uaic.ro/~elena.chiosa/img/scoci.png">
    <img id="two" src="http://fenrir.info.uaic.ro/~elena.chiosa/img/scoci.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Oohh, I understand now! Thank you for the explanation! I'll make sure to never misuse it again.

Answer (score 2):

You're using position:relative when you should be using position:absolute.

```css
body {
  background: gray;
}
.container {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: navy;
  position: relative;
}
.container #one {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(-25%, -25%)
}
.container #two {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  transform: translate(-75%, -25%) rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://www.animal-photography.com/thumbs/blue_eyed_white_long_hair_cat_~AP-G3KLBP-TH.jpg" />
  <img id="one" src="http://fenrir.info.uaic.ro/~elena.chiosa/img/scoci.png" />
  <img id="two" src="http://fenrir.info.uaic.ro/~elena.chiosa/img/scoci.png" />
</div>
```

That said, I'd prefer not to have presentational images in the HTML at all. So I'd be using pseudo-elements using the same techniques.

```css
body {
  background: gray;
}
.container {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: navy;
  position: relative;
}
.container::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-image: url(http://fenrir.info.uaic.ro/~elena.chiosa/img/scoci.png);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(-25%, -25%);
  z-index: 1;
}
.container::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-image: url(http://fenrir.info.uaic.ro/~elena.chiosa/img/scoci.png);
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  transform: translate(-75%, -25%) rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://www.animal-photography.com/thumbs/blue_eyed_white_long_hair_cat_~AP-G3KLBP-TH.jpg" />
</div>
```

In this way, the presentational part is now in the CSS and the class can be re-used without having multiple instances of the tape image cluttering up your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `position: absolute;` instead of `position: relative;`

```
.container #one{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left:20px;
}

.container #two{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left:215px;

    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/mtsgp3gg/1/)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer but I'm confused. Shouldn't I be thinking "I want the tapes to be positioned relative to the container"?